# Old Ubuntu Desktop Failing to Update (Failed to fetch)

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

My colleagues and I are attempting to run some updates on a computer with Ubuntu 12.10, which has been unused for some time. However, when we try running sudo apt-get update the terminal returns several error messages, of which here is a sample:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

The full log is here: http://pastebin.com/s9kD0NX6

I've heard some have had the same problem, apparently Ubuntu cannot handle large amounts of updates? At the moment, we have about 500 to install :(

How would we go about fixing this problem? Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Quantal has passed end-of-life and is no longer distributed on the main Ubuntu mirrors.  (If you try loading those URLs in your web browser, you'll find they really are 404 - nothing to do with Ubuntu being able to handle "large amounts of updates".)

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace `us.archive.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, which is a site that still hosts this old software.  For repositories that contain software that is not part of core Ubuntu (`security.ubuntu.com`, `ppa.launchpad.net`, `dl.google.com`, etc), you may want to simply comment them out from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the corresponding files in `sources.list.d`, and then re-enable them once you have upgraded to a currently supported version.

Since such old versions are not supported and likely have security bugs that are not being patched, you will probably want to upgrade to a current version ASAP.  Note that you will have to do several upgrades in succession: to 13.04, then 13.10, 14.04.  You can stay there if you want as 14.04 is a long-term-support release which is still supported.  Otherwise you can proceed with 14.10, 15.04, 15.10.

You might consider whether it is easier to simply start over and reinstall with a current version.